# Can Bitmaps be written to cache using ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: android, file-io, bitmap, serializable, fileoutputstream

I have a method called loadFromCache and it returns a bitmap if it is found in the cache. Long story short I have it narrowed down to this method, returning null at the end if the try/catch fails.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getCacheDir()+(""+position));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)ois.readObject();
        fis.close();
        return temp;
```

I have previously tried the Bitmap.compress(...) methods to save bitmaps but they were a little slow for my needs... Yes the bitmap has been written to these positions, but I don't know if it (Bitmap) is serializable so is it actually saving? And yes I remembered to flush when I wrote the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is `Bitmap.compress()` too slow for you? The only faster(?) way would be to write the bitmap unchanged to disk, see below.

Using [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) together with [`Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) may work. I haven't tested this but it seems like it could work. Note that you most likely will have to store image dimensions yourself.

Comment: You see, for what I'm doing, it really doesn't make sense to compress the bitmaps to pngs in class A and then decode them 5 seconds later in class B where I need the same bitmaps created in class A... I've been having troubles reading the files into my AnimationDrawable using the decode stream. I have a subclass that extends drawable and receives a bitmap in the constructor. Then when I try to add the files, nothing shows up on the AnimationDrawable, but when I addFrames from R.drawable, it works fine.

Comment: Here's the code I'm using                                                    for(int x=0; x<numberFiles; x++){
 FileInputStream in = openFileInput(getCacheDir()+"preview"+x+".png");
 Drawable nadMe = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
 animation.addFrame(nadMe, 50);
 in.close();                                                                  }

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an experience I just had with Bitmap.compress being very slow:

My source image was a jpeg, and I was passing Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG to bitmap.compress.  This caused the compress operation to take 10-15 seconds.

Once I changed it to JPEG (such that the source and destination file remain the same image format) then the operation takes less than a second.  Perhaps the original question came about through a similar means, and maybe someone else finds this helpful.